# how to get the ip and port of the client side for each packet of data on grpc server side which implement by java?

Tags: java, server, ip, client, grpc

I want to get the client ip and port corresponding to each packet of data by java grpc service.

```
service Auxiliary {
  rpc ProcessMessage(AuxiliaryGrpcMsgRequest) returns (AuxiliaryGrpcMsgReply) {
  }
}
```

this method is generated by proto

```java
public void processMessage( AuxiliaryGrpcMsgRequest request, 
           StreamObserver<AuxiliaryGrpcMsgReply> responseObserver) {

}
```

I want know corresponding IP and port of request . I used ServerInterceptor to get IP, but Interceptor thread is different with this processMessage thread. I don't want to use lock to synchronize the two threads, so I want to see if there is any way to get the ip and port of the client corresponding to the request directly in one thread

I noticed C++ can use context->peer() to achieve this.but java's context have no peer(), is there any way to slove this?

Comment: The Java GRPC package does not start a webserver for you, it depends on an existing webserver to run on. Depending on what webserver or application framework you use there can be different ways to give you the IP address. Can you explain a bit more on the setup of your java app?

Comment: this method is generated by proto
public void processMessage(
        AuxiliaryGrpcMsgRequest request, StreamObserver<AuxiliaryGrpcMsgReply> responseObserver) {
  
}

I want know  corresponding IP and port of request . I used  ServerInterceptor to get IP, but Interceptor thread is different with this processMessage thread.
I don't want to use lock to synchronize the two threads, so I want to see if there is any way to get the ip and port of the client corresponding to the request directly in one thread

Comment: by the way I noticed C++ can get the client information of the request by context.peer() in the same thread,does java have same implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

This information is available to interceptors via `serverCall.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR)`. If you want it in the `Context`, you'd need to use a `ServerInterceptor` to copy it to the `Context`.

Comment: serverCall and message are in different thread some times, do you know to avoid this.

Comment: Each callback can be on a different thread. When using Context, you use Context.interceptCall() to set the context for each callback. If you are manually passing the message to another thread, then you'd need to also pass the Context (or IP directly).

Comment: java api have no this Context.interceptCall() api ?how to get this ? can you give an example ?

Comment: It is Contexts.interceptCall(). https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Contexts.html